# I need an array of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays

Javascript Code:

```
var simvalue = $('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').each(function() {
        var sim_name=this.value.split(" ")[0];
        console.log("simname:",sim_name);
        var sim_list = [{
            simulation_name : sim_name,
        }];
        console.log(sim_list);
    });
```

I need an array of selected checkboxes in sim_list.. currently the array of values are replaced with the same index ie Array[1].. I need values like 1,2,3,4 in 'var simvalue'

Comment: `var sim_list = $('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').map(function(){ return {simulation_name: this.value.split(" ")[0]}; }).toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Your are not pushing data to array instead you are re initiating array

try like this

```
var sim_list=[];
var simvalue = $('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').each(function() {
        var sim_name=this.value.split(" ")[0];
        console.log("simname:",sim_name);
        sim_list.push({
            simulation_name : sim_name,
        });

    });
console.log(sim_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning the array instead of adding to it here

```
var sim_list = [{
    simulation_name : sim_name,
}];
```

Also there should not be any `,` when setting only one property to an object or on the last property. You can use `push` to add to an array.

```
sim_list.push({simulation_name : sim_name});
```

with `sim_list` delcared as an empty array BEFORE the loop.

```
var sim_list = [];

$('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').each(function() {

    var sim_name = this.value.split(" ")[0];

    sim_list.push({
        simulation_name : sim_name // comma removed to avoid errors
    });

});
```

See [push documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fpush)

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you are reassigning the array in each loop so all of the previous values are lost.

The [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function can get all the values you want and put them into an array:

```js
$(function() {

// Call map on your selector
var result = $('input[name="simnamecbx"]:checked').map(function() {    
  // return the values you want in the array
  return { simulation_name: this.value.split(' ')[0] };
}).get(); // get returns the result as an array

// Output result
$.each(result, function(i, val) {
    $('#result').append("Simulation name: " + val.simulation_name + "<br />");
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="simnamecbx" value="test1 1" checked="checked" /> 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="simnamecbx" value="test2 2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="simnamecbx" value="test3 3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="simnamecbx" value="test4 4" checked="checked" /> 4 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="simnamecbx" value="test5 5" /> 5 <br />

<div id="result"></div>
```